# Unhandled Exeption: System.NullReferenceExeption: Object reference not set to an instance of an object C#

Tags: c#

resulta que tengo esta funcion en C# la cual me permite almacenar canciones en un Array de tipo struct, como pueden ver yo puse un ciclo for y la variable controladora i debe llegar hasta <= c.Length, (c) es la de instancia del array tipo struct, se supone que guarda la longitud del array que en este caso es de 100(Aunque creo que estoy confundiendo la capacidad que se le asigna al array con su longitud, ahi me corrigen), aunque de todas formas antes le había puesto que llegara hasta i<100 y me sacaba el mismo error de todas formas ,

El caso esque no entiendo porque me sale este error en consola: **Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceExeption: Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

Que parece ser que falta la instancia de un objeto pero no se cual, agradeceria su ayuda, gracias.

```
public struct tipoCanciones { 

        public string nombre;
        public string album; 
        public int año;
        public string artista; 

        } 

public class Canciones {   

int contador = 0;

 static tipoCanciones [] c = new tipoCanciones[100];

 public Canciones (int contador){

  this.contador = contador;

}        


public void Añadir(int contador){ 
Console.WriteLine("ESTE PROGRAMA LE PERMITIRA GUARDAR HASTA 100 CANCIONES");

string r = null;
while (r!="No" || r!="no" || r!="NO")
{
  bool cancionguard = false;
  r = "si";
  for(int i=0; i<c.Length; i++){
      Console.WriteLine("Digite el titulo de la cancion");
      string titulo = Console.ReadLine();
      Console.WriteLine("Digite el artista de la cancion");
      string art = Console.ReadLine(); 
      if(c[i].artista.Contains(art) && c[i].nombre.Contains(titulo)){  
        Console.WriteLine("La cancion que intenta almacenar ya se encuentra en la lista");
        break;

      }else{
      c[i].nombre = titulo;
      Console.WriteLine("Digite el album de la cancion");
      c[i].album = (Console.ReadLine());
      Console.WriteLine("Digite el año de la cancion");
      c[i].año = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      Console.WriteLine("Digite el artista de la cancion");
      c[i].artista = art;
      Console.WriteLine("Desea seguir guardando canciones?: SI/NO");
      cancionguard = true;
      r = Console.ReadLine();

      if(r=="Si" || r=="si" || r=="SI"){

        this.contador++; 

        }else{

          break;
        }


      }
}

if(cancionguard)
 {
    break;
 } 

  Console.WriteLine("Desea intentar guardar otra cancion?");
  r = Console.ReadLine();

}

Menu();

}
```

Comment: Qué tiene esto que ver con java? Por favor, etiqueta bien tus preguntas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que haces mal es que deberías introducir esta línea de código que te asegura crear el objeto tipoCanciones

```
c[i] = new tipoCanciones();
```

Una vez iniciada la estructura ya puedes rellenarla:

```
c[i].titulo = ...
c[i].artista = ...
```

También puedes crear un constructor dentro de tu tipo de datos tipoCanciones y rellenar mientras lo declaras; una vez tuvieras todos los datos harías así:

```
c[i] = new tipoCanciones(titulo, art,...);
```

Tu estructura quedaría algo así:

```
    public struct tipoCanciones { 

        public string nombre;
        public string album; 
        public int año;
        public string artista; 

        public tipoCanciones(string p_Nombre, string p_Artista, string p_Album, int p_Año)
        {
              nombre = p_Nombre;
              album = p_Album;
              año= p_Año;
              artista = p_Artista;
        }
    }
```

Otra cosa entorno al código, tu línea de código:

```
   if(c[i].artista.Contains(art) && c[i].nombre.Contains(titulo)){  
        Console.WriteLine("La cancion que intenta almacenar ya se encuentra en la lista");
        break;

   }
```

No está haciendo una comparación de los artistas o canciones introducidas, esa línea sólo compara el artista con el propio artísta que estás tratando de crear en el índice i. Para hacer una comparación correcta tendrías que recorrer el array he aquí una función de muestra:

```
private bool ExisteEnLaLista(string art, string titulo)
{
     for(int i=0; i < c.Length; i++)
     {
         if (c[i] != null) // Si el objeto existe entonces comparo
         {
               if(c[i].artista.ToUpper() == art.ToUpper() &&
                  c[i].nombre.ToUpper() == titulo.ToUpper) return true;
         }
         else              // Si no existe no sigo buscando
             return false;
     }
}
```

Con esto ya sólo tendrías que llamar a la función y obrar en consecuencia:

```
if(ExisteEnLaLista(art,titulo) 
{  
    Console.WriteLine("La cancion que intenta almacenar ya se encuentra en la lista");
    break;
}
```